# Php loop with different echo text

Tags: php, loops

I'm just started to learn php and have a lot of questions and all answers i found here, but i stucked on one problem and don't know which search words i need to use to find answer, so:
I need to make some kind of loop with different echo text, but every new line should have $line+1, for example like this:

```
$line=1;
Echo 'this line has number ='.$line;
$line=$line+1;
Echo 'this is second line'.$line;
$line=$line+1;
Echo ' third line'.$line;
```

I know that it simpliest way to do what i want, but php guru will make same thing in other easiest way. 
Could you help m, please?

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is to store the elements in an array, then using `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`Array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to store your text. Then you can loop through it with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
<?php
$textArray = ["First text", "Other text", "Final text"];
foreach ($textArray as $key=>$value) {
    $key++;
    echo "Line $key - $value" . "<br>";
}
?>
```

This prints

```
Line 1 - First text
Line 2 - Other text
Line 3 - Final text
```

The `$key` variable is the index of your array (or in your case line number). We use the `$key++` to increment the variable with 1 so it doesn't start on line number 0.

The `$value` variable is the text in your array element.

Comment: I need to echo different text on each line.

Comment: You just need to store your elements in an array - see my updated answer @DmitrijsKuzmins

Comment: Thanks, look like what i need!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do with  a for loop

```
     for($i=1;$i<10;$i++)
        {
        echo"This line number = $i";
        }
```

Syntax of for loop is:

```
for (init value;condition; increment) 
{
    code to be executed;
}
```

You can use variable inside double quote i.e. variable inside double 
quote will be replaced with it's value.Or
    you can use a while loop instead

```
    $i=1
    while(i<10)
    {
    echo"This line number = $i";
    }
```

Syntax for while loop is simple

```
while(condition)
{
code to be execute
}
```